# Can't get values when looping over an array of arrays

Tags: perl

I created an array like so:

```
while(@results = $execute->fetchrow())
{
  my $active = 'true';

  if($results[1] == 0)
  {
    $active = 'false';
  }

  my @campaign = ($results[0], $active);
  push(@campaign_names, @campaign);
}
```

Later, when I need to access the name of the campaign (which is the first element of the campaign array), I can't seem to extract it. What is the proper syntax?

```
foreach $campaign (@campaign_names)
{
  print ????;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if I'm using the push function incorrectly. Hmmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're pushing an array onto the end of `@campaign_names`, when what you want is an array reference. Here's how I'd write it:

```
while(@results = $execute->fetchrow())
{
  my $active = $results[1] ? 'true' : 'false';
  push @campaign_names, [ $results[0], $active ];
}

# later

foreach my $campaign( @campaign_names ) 
{ 
    my $name = $campaign->[0]; 
    my $active = $campaign->[1];
}
```

I've cleaned it up a bit by using a ternary conditional (`?:`) to figure out the value of `$active`. The `[ ... ]` constructs an anonymous array reference (a scalar pointing to an array) which is then pushed onto `@campaign_names`.

When we loop over those later, two important things to notice are that we use `my` in the loop variable to keep it local to the loop block, and that we use `->` to dereference the elements in the array pointed to by the array reference.

Comment: @Darkwater23, because campaign is not an array, it's a scalar. You need to dereference the scalar into an array via `$campaign->[0]` or `@{$campaign}[0]`.

Comment: @Darkwater23, take a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html for more on references.

Answer (score 1):

That's not creating an array of arrays. `my @campaign = ($results[0], $active); push(@campaign_names, @campaign);` flattens and pushes `$results[0]` and  `$active` into the `@campaign_names` array. Instead, push an arrayref:

```
  my @campaign = ($results[0], $active);
  push(@campaign_names, \@campaign);
```

or

```
  my $campaign = [$results[0], $active];
  push(@campaign_names, $campaign);
```

Arrays can only hold scalar values.

You'll want to refer to perldsc as you learn (perldoc perldsc, http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)